# Hibernate hbm2ddl on hsqldb create table with default value varchar column : unexpected token

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb, hbm2ddl

I try to generate schema on hsqldb for unit tests, I get an issue when creating table with column default value. It says in documentation that the default value for varchar must be single quote. But it doesn't work when a had single quotes in my hbm file. Without quotes I get another error : **unexpected token:Europe** because of the "/" I think.

```
ERROR 20-07-2017 09:55:48   HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table PUBLIC.COMPANY (ID_COMPANY varchar not null, DESCR_COMPANY varchar not null,  COMPANY_TIMEZONE varchar default 'Europe/Brussels', primary key (ID_COMPANY)) - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:235)

ERROR 20-07-2017 09:55:48   unexpected token: : - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:236)
```

**update** try to escape with / and without single cotes

```
ERROR 20-07-2017 15:40:57   HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table PUBLIC.COMPANY_EA (ID_COMPANY varchar not null, DESCR_COMPANY varchar not null, COMPANY_TIMEZONE varchar default Europe\/Brussels,  primary key (ID_COMPANY)) - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:235)
ERROR 20-07-2017 15:40:57   unexpected token: EUROPE - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:236)
```

It's the same error than without cote, I try with single quotes and escaping change nothing.

It looks that special words eg:'NONE', 'STANDBY', 'DAY' involve an error too.

**update** quotes + escaping

```
ERROR 20-07-2017 15:58:55   HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table PUBLIC.COMPANY_EA (ID_COMPANY varchar not null, DESCR_COMPANY varchar not null, COMPANY_TIMEZONE varchar default 'Europe\/Brussels',  primary key (ID_COMPANY)) - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:235)
ERROR 20-07-2017 15:58:55   unexpected token: : - org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:236)
```

Comment: Try escaping `/` character using `\/`. i.e. provide default value as `Europe\/Brussels`

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala I tried and update my question with that test.

Comment: Try providing quotes as you were doing earlier. Dont remove the quotes. Just add the escape character.

Comment: I tried too, with single quotes, but same result that without escaping /